# Why is the quantum kernel $\kappa(x,x')=|\langle\phi(x)|\phi(x')\rangle|^2$ defined with a square?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-methods, quantum-kernel

I've always wondered why the quantum kernel method

\begin{equation}\label{QKM1}
\kappa (x,x')=|\langle \phi(x) |\phi(x') \rangle {{|}^{2}}
\end{equation}

must be a square. After reading [“Supervised learning with quantum-enhanced feature spaces"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.11326) by V. Havlíček, A. D. Córcoles et al. and [“Quantum machine learning in feature Hilbert spaces”](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.07128) by
M. Schuld, and N. Killoran, it was not straightforward to discover the derivation of this formula.

Furthermore, is $\kappa (x,x')=|\langle \phi(x) |\phi(x') \rangle {{|}^{2}}$ a semi-positive definite matrix?

Comment: One observation that could help: note that if we have $\rho(x)=\vert \phi(x) \rangle\langle \phi(x) \vert$ and $\rho(x')=\vert \phi(x') \rangle\langle \phi(x') \vert$, then $\kappa$ corresponds to the Hilbert-Schmit inner product: $\kappa(x,x')=\mathrm{Tr}(\rho(x)^\dagger \rho(x'))$

Comment: related, though without the absolute value: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28666/advantage-of-density-matrix-over-vector-to-form-quantum-kernel?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** There could be other reasons, too, but without the square $\kappa$ fails to be [positive semidefinite (PSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Definitions_for_real_matrices).

### Summary

As in classical machine learning, the kernel function $\kappa$ is supposed to be the inner product in the latent space. Therefore, $\kappa(x_i,x_j)$ must be PSD. If it is defined with the square, then it is the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix) $\langle\phi(x_i)|\phi(x_j)\rangle$ with its complex conjugate, both of which are PSD. Since Hadamard product sends a pair of PSD matrices to a PSD matrix, $\kappa$ with the square is PSD. On the other hand, elementwise absolute value of a PSD matrix may fail to be PSD, so $\kappa$ without the square may fail to be PSD.

Intuitively, the "right" way of obtaining a real inner product from a complex inner product is not by taking the absolute value, but by multiplying it with its complex conjugate. This is related to the fact that the L2 norm is induced by an inner product, but L1 norm is not.

### Background

The key assumption behind the kernel methods is that $\kappa:\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{X}\to\mathbb{R}$ is an inner product $\langle.,.\rangle_\mathcal{L}$ in the latent space $\mathcal{L}$
$$
\kappa(x, x')=\langle f(x),f(x')\rangle_\mathcal{L}\tag1
$$
where $f:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{L}$ is the feature map from the input space $\mathcal{X}$ to the latent space $\mathcal{L}$. However, for $\kappa$ to admit this expression it must induce a PSD matrix for any finite set of $n$ points of $\mathcal{X}$, i.e. $\sum_{i,j=1}^nc_ic_j\kappa(x_i,x_j)\geq 0$ for any $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\mathcal{X}$ and any $c_1,\dots,c_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

### Good and bad $\kappa$

Now, let's define two functions:
$$
\begin{align}
\kappa_{\text{good}}(x,x')&:=|\langle\phi(x)|\phi(x')\rangle|^2,\tag2\\
\kappa_{\text{bad}}(x,x')&:=|\langle\phi(x)|\phi(x')\rangle|.\tag{2'}
\end{align}
$$

**Claim 1** $\kappa_{\text{good}}(x,x')$ is PSD.

**Proof**
Let $\lambda(x,x'):=\langle\phi(x)|\phi(x')\rangle$. By definition, $\lambda(x_i,x_j)$ is a Gram matrix, so it is PSD. Moreover, the complex conjugate of $\lambda(x_i,x_j)$ is PSD, too. But then $$\kappa(x_i,x_j)=\overline{\lambda(x_i,x_j)}\lambda(x_i,x_j)\tag3$$ is the Hadamard (elementwise) product of two PSD matrices. By [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem), $\kappa(x_i,x_j)$ is PSD. $\square$

We can avoid the use of Schur product theorem by constructing the inner product space $\mathcal{L}$ and the feature map $f$ such that $\kappa_{\text{good}}(x,x')=\langle f(x),f(x')\rangle_\mathcal{L}$. This can be done by setting $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{H}\otimes\overline{\mathcal{H}}$ where $\overline{\mathcal{H}}$ is the same as $\mathcal{H}$ except the inner product in $\overline{\mathcal{H}}$ is the complex conjugate of the inner product in $\mathcal{H}$ and by defining $f:\mathcal{X}\to\mathcal{L}$ via $f(x)=|\phi(x)\rangle\langle\phi(x)|$.

**Claim 2** $\kappa_{\text{bad}}(x,x')$ is not necessarily PSD.

**Proof** Let $\mathcal{X}=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and define
$$
\begin{align}
|\phi(0)\rangle=\sqrt{\frac23}|0\rangle+\sqrt{\frac16}|1\rangle-\sqrt{\frac16}|3\rangle\tag4\\
|\phi(1)\rangle=\sqrt{\frac16}|0\rangle+\sqrt{\frac23}|1\rangle+\sqrt{\frac16}|2\rangle\tag5\\
|\phi(2)\rangle=\sqrt{\frac16}|1\rangle+\sqrt{\frac23}|2\rangle+\sqrt{\frac16}|3\rangle\tag6\\
|\phi(3)\rangle=-\sqrt{\frac16}|0\rangle+\sqrt{\frac16}|2\rangle+\sqrt{\frac23}|3\rangle.\tag7
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\kappa_{\text{bad}}(x_i,x_j)=\begin{bmatrix}
1&\frac23&0&\frac23\\
\frac23&1&\frac23&0\\
0&\frac23&1&\frac23\\
\frac23&0&\frac23&1
\end{bmatrix}\tag8
$$
has $-\frac13$ among its eigenvalues.
$\square$

Credit: the quantum states $(4{-}7)$ are derived from the second matrix in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1356349).

Comment: just a note: in the context of kernel methods, "positive semidefinite" is understood as $\sum_{ij} c_i c_j \kappa(x_i,x_j)\ge0$ for all real coefficients $c_i$, not $\kappa(x_i,x_j)\ge0$. In fact, you could in general have $\kappa(x,y)<0$ for $x\neq y$. In practice, the $\kappa$ needs to be PSD *as a matrix*. Here you clearly have $\kappa(x_i,x_j)\ge0$, but it's (slightly) less obvious that the stronger condition applies. It still does if the kernel is defined as an inner product b/c $\sum c_i c_j\kappa(x_i,x_j)=\|\sum c_i f(x_i)\|^2$ if $\kappa(x,y)\equiv \langle f(x),f(y)\rangle$.

Comment: I treat $\kappa$ as a matrix and define PSD the usual way: $\kappa$ is PSD if $c^T\kappa c=\sum_{ij}c_ic_j\kappa(x_i,x_j)\geq 0$ for all vectors $c=[c_0,\dots,c_n]^T$. In general, we actually need a slightly more general definition when $\mathcal{X}$ is an infinite set (and then the definition says that $\kappa$ is a PSD _function_ if every $\kappa(x_i,x_j)$ is a PSD matrix), but this subtlety does not enter the picture here). I don't think I say or imply that PSD means $\kappa(x_i,x_j)\geq 0$? This is just "elementwise non-negative"...

Comment: I've also thought about the understanding that adding even powers would make $\kappa (x,{x}')=|\langle \phi (x)|\phi ({x}')\rangle {{|}^{2}}$ a positive number. But it quickly became apparent that negative eigenvalues would still exceptionally exist despite the premise that the output is positive. How can I prove in a strict sense at which even powers PSD can be realized?

Comment: @R-XZhao Yes, elementwise non-negativity is certainly insufficient for $\kappa$ to be PSD, as we see in $(8)$. However, if $\kappa$ is defined as an _even_ power of $|\langle\phi(x)|\phi(x')\rangle|$ then it is in fact PSD. This can be proved by repeated application of the [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) as I did in the above proof of Claim 1. Also, note that you don't need even powers to make $|\langle\phi(x)|\phi(x')\rangle|$ non-negative. This we have for all powers from the absolute value.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the matrix in (8), e.g. the top right element should be $|\langle \phi(0) | \phi(3)\rangle | = |\sqrt{2/3} \cdot (-\sqrt{1/6}) +  (-\sqrt{1/6}) \cdot (-\sqrt{2/3}) | = 0$. When I checked, the set of states you provided gave a valid kernel matrix, at least if the kets are an orthonormal basis...

Comment: @forky40 There was a typo (wrong sign) in $|\phi(3)\rangle$. Thanks for catching! Note that $|\phi(i)\rangle$ are not orthonormal.